# Javascript: webpack bundle not exporting expected function

Tags: javascript, webpack, javascriptcore

I am trying to bundle the Javascript library [cookpete/poker-odds](https://github.com/cookpete/poker-odds) so I can use it in Swift JavascriptCore. When I bundle the code with `webpack`, and then run `const bundle = require("./bundle.js")` in Node REPL, `bundle` is an empty object. I expect this object to export the functions marked with `export` in the source code. I tried modifying the code (added `module.exports = {...}`) before bundling to ensure my desired function is exported, but there was still nothing exported.

My process:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/cookpete/poker-odds.git && cd poker-odds
npm run build // generate the /lib directory
add webpack.config.js // see below
npx webpack // generate bundle.js in dist directory
cd dist // move to dist directory
node // launch node REPL
const bundle = require("./bundle.js")
console.log("bundle:", bundle) // prints bundle: {}; I want this object to contain calculateEquity()
```

```js
webpack.config.js:
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './lib/calculate.js', // Is this correct?
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

Questions:

- What is the correct `entry` property for `webpack.config.js`? I'm unclear on what I need to export the `calculateEquity()` function.
- The library uses `babel`. Is this causing a problem?
- The library appears to generate a `.json` file during building. Is this a problem?

Thanks.